# Control android device volume using external headset or other connected device

Tags: android, bluetooth

Trying to make a simple application,in which after connecting android phone to bluetooth headset,when we press volume buttons on headset device it must change volume of android device.
So basically trying to control android device volume using bluetooth headsets.

Is there any way to do this ?
TIA

Comment: I think you don't have to code anything for it. Once the bluetooth headset is connected, the operating system itself will manage the volume keys

Comment: what if i want to do something else with it e.g. change music or change some value ,is there any kind of trigger?